# How can I use facet_wrap using pie charts?

Tags: r

```
Seasons Frequency1  Frequency2
DJF      497        500
JJA      999        700
MAM      695        2000
SON      245        1000
```

Hi, I am making multiple pie charts using this dataframe (One using Frequency1, another using Frequency2). I know how to use melt and facet_wrap(~id). But here I have to pool the data (Don't know how to express it). I don't want to Facet_wrap by Seasons.

How can I melt the data in a way that I can make two pie charts side by side. I have made one using just Frequency1.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to melt and use facets, then:

```
library(reshape2)
molten_df <- melt(your_df, id.var='Seasons')
```

Now molten_df will have a column called 'variable' which you can use for facets:

```
+facet_grid(facets=.~variable)
```

However, if you just want two charts side by side, you can also just arrange them. I find the gridExtra package to be handy for this:

```
library(gridExtra) # will also load the grid package. install these if needed.

# however you are creating your charts
plot1 <- ... #your code here
plot2 <- ... #your code here

# side by side
grid.arrange (plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I was aware of this. But since I would be having 4-5 plots, I wanted a cleaner code using facet.wrap. If no one else posts, I'll use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach to generate a pie chart with facetting using `ggplot2`.

The data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Seasons Frequency1  Frequency2
DJF      497        500
JJA      999        700
MAM      695        2000
SON      245        1000", header = TRUE)
```

Transform the data into the long format:

```
library(reshape2) 
dat2 <- melt(dat)
```

Create the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = Seasons)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, position = position_fill()) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") + 
  facet_wrap( ~ variable)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, how can I make the labels the season names instead of numbers like the figure in my question?

Comment: Adding the following line labels the pie chart on the left: `+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.75, 0.95), labels = as.character(dat$Seasons))` As far as I know, you can't have independent scales with `coord_polar`, so you have to combine the two posted solutions. You have to make two plots and use the `grid.arrange` function mentioned above. And has anyone ever told you that pie charts have no place in data visualization? (and is probably one of the reasons why it is not a default ggplot geom)

Comment: Yes, my Professor disagreees. :-) Thank you though.